# Delete all characters after digits in a string in Presto

Tags: sql, string, replace, presto, regexp-replace

I have a string like 'de22128350490finazamthersbruck' and I want to remove all characters after digits, so the output should be like "de22128350490"also there isn't any pattern to detect that.

I tried many ways as :

```
REPLACE(field_name, '[^A-Za-z]', ' ')
regexp_replace([field_name], '(?<=[^[^A-Za-z]])/$', '')
```

but not getting clear data

Comment: _"also there isn't any pattern to detect that"_ -  if you have not found it it does not mean one does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_extract` with following pattern worked for me - `.*[^A-Za-z]` (see [@regex101](https://regex101.com/r/v5iEtw/1)):

```sql
select regexp_extract('de22128350490finazamthersbruck', '.*[^A-z]');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| de22128350490 |

Comment: thanks, I also used "'[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]+|[0-9]+'" and that word as well

Comment: @NegiiinFa was glad to help. If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left)